# tensorflow object Detection API training, tensorboard don't show image

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

When I use tensorflow object detection AIP training my customized data, in tensorboard everything work fine, except image. in image window, it show two cumulative normalized values plot
[image]

[image]

anyone can tell me that's why?
I have set num_visualizations in eval config, still not work.

I just want it can show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should execute evel.py to product evel reuslt, than the tensorboard will show this kind of picture

Comment: Hi there, how did you get the result at a certain step slider? My Images tab only shows the result at the current step...

Comment: I think you should execute evel.py many times in different training step,just like any other MLproject: train->eval->train->eval....

Comment: I actually execute eval.py every 10 minutes, but my TensorBoard only how the resulting bounding boxes at the latest evaluation. So I was wondering how you got the "slider" that can compare the result at different steps.

Comment: @Emide before eval.py make sure export model with export_inference_graph.py